# Inserting Image into InLines list of paragraph

Tags: c#, wpf, image, flowdocument, paragraph

I need to include an image in a paragraph alongside some text. However, I need to insert the image *after* the text has been added.
I know that I can do this:

```
Paragraph firstParagraph = new Paragraph();
firstParagraph.Inlines.Add(new System.Windows.Controls.Image());
firstParagraph.Inlines.Add(new Run("Some text"));
```

which works fine.

However, if I can't seem to do this:

```
Paragraph secondParagraph = new Paragraph();
secondParagraph.Inlines.Add(new Run("Some text"));
secondParagraph.Inlines.InsertBefore(secondParagraph.Inlines.FirstInline, new Image());
```

(Obviously the above is a contrived example, in my real-world example I get a long list of Paragraphs back, over which I have no control. I need to insert an image at the front of some them.)

Comment: Why can't you do this? Is there an error? Does it not work?

Comment: yes, more details please

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to know where to insert.
You will need a TextPointer.

Given you are using a RichTextBox and you want to insert at cursor position try:

```
RichTextBox.Name = "rtb";
```

your System.Windows.Controls.Image name: img

```
TextPointer insertHere = rtb.CaretPosition.GetInsertionPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
new InlineUIContainer(img, insertHere);
```